# Add Marathi(Devnagri) font in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, fonts, blackberry-simulator

I want to add Marathi(Devnagri) font in my simulator how can i achieve that?

Once i m done with it and deployed on actual blackberry phone then same language i.e. marathi(Devnagri)should be added on Blackberry phone?

Comment: Are you asking about BB 7 and earlier (i.e. Java) or BB10?  If BB7, have you seen this? http://developer.blackberry.com/bbos/java/documentation/Fonts_1970229_11.html.  If BB10, havw you looked at this: http://devblog.blackberry.com/2013/08/cascades-ui-framework-improvements-in-10-2/ and this: http://devblog.blackberry.com/2012/07/blackberry-10-font-changes/

Comment: My app contents the text in Devnagri(Marathi)language.I want to test that same in simulator.Your help on this would be appreciable